# How to make Gson read value as String?

Tags: gson

My JSON objects look like this

```
{"phoneNbr":"123456789","firstName":"Mark","previousNames":[{"previous1":"Peter","previous2":"Steve"}]}

{"phoneNbr":"234567891","firstName":"Hank","previousNames":null}
```

The `previousNames` values can be anything. I want it to be treated a STRING always. However when I try to parse it, GSON complaints because it expects array.

---

`PersonJsonDAO` class looks like this

```
private String phoneNbr; 
private String firstName; 
private String previousNames;
```

---

I try to parse it but GSON says `Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY`

```
PersonJsonDAO personJsonDAO= new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, PersonJsonDAO.class);
```

**How can I force GSON to accept `previousNames` as `String`?**

Comment: Who are those backend engineers who generate such a response.

Comment: json is proper. i was slightly exaggerating. i corrected the test json.  the point is i want the object to treated as string. just read it as string. cannot find how to do this. i looked up adapters, but don't understand how to make this seemingly simple thing work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GSON is treating it as an array, because it is indeed an array :)
I can think of 4 different alternatives to meet your desired behavior:

1. A preprocessing step of turning everything after '"previousNames":' into a string, by searching for the first occurance of '"previousNames":[', inserting there a '"', backspacing all the double quotes, till the occurrence of ']', before which I would add another double quote.
2. a much easier solution, if you don't mind the slight computational overhead, which in your case is probably tiny, just parse into a JSON as a first step, like you did, but declaring previousNames as an array of Strings, and then calling:

   personJsonDAO.getString("previousNames");
   However, this will leave you with previousNames field as an array of Strings.
3. Another option is to leave it as a JSonObject in the deserilization process, like this: 
   class PersonJsonDAO { 
       ....
       @SerializedName("previousNames")
       JsonObject previousNames;
       ....
   }
4. If the above alternatives are not enough, and you insist on having the previousNames field as a String, then the most comprehensive and correct approach would be to override the desiarilzation process of GSON, calling super for all behaviours, except when meeting the  previousNames culprit, which you would return as a String.